# rails 3.2 development mode is not displaying the full error page with backtrace etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded to rails 3.2 Everything is working fine except error pages no longer show the normal development debug info. Instead it's showing the standard production error page (white background with red text in the middle:

"We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

Is there a new setting or something I'm missing for rails 3.2? I've read over the upgrade instructions and do not see it mentioned anywhere. I tried downgrading to 3.1.3 and the error pages work again so this is definitely a rails 3.2 issue. Thanks.

Comment: Check the `config.consider_all_requests_local` inside `development.rb`. It must be set to `true` in order to show full error reports.

Comment: @jibiel thanks! If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it. It's weird that I was getting full error reports in 3.1 with this setting = false but not in 3.2. Solved.

Comment: That's pretty weird indeed. Please post back here if you find some clues.

Comment: This was obviously not the problem in your case, but since I got here googling a similar issue: if you see a white 500 error page with no debug info in dev, and the same page instead of the 404 page in prod, you probably need to update/use another another fork of will_paginate: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/pull/215

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the `config.consider_all_requests_local` inside `development.rb`. It must be set to `true` in order to show full error reports.

Comment: I have that, but still see no error in the log when the view fails to render. Errors in controllers are shown properly.

Comment: @NicolasMarchildon any update on how you solve this? I just get the same bug on a project that was working few months ago. (I'm checking all the git diff...)

Comment: Finally got it. The gem web-console was updated and cause the bug.

Answer (score 4):

**Nicolas**, I'm faced the same problem and only saw the message `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` and nothing in logs.

The problem was in `UTF-8 characters`, so adding encoding declaration to the beginning of the file solved it:

```
# encoding = utf-8
```

Comment: Which file does this go at the beginning of? the view?

Comment: @unclesol Just Ruby files (controllers, models, etc): `*.rb`

Comment: I don't suppose there is any way to do this without editing every individual file?

Answer (score 0):

If neither jibiels nor Dmitrys solution helped, try out the solution mentioned here:
[Rails doesnt log tempalte errors in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624208/rails-doesnt-log-tempalte-errors-in-development-mode/17978388#17978388)

(Maybe this also helps you, @Nicolas)